# If $A \overline X = aX$ then $|a|^{2}$ is an eigenvalue of $A \overline A$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$|a|^{2} = \overline a \cdot a$ so we can say that:

$$A \overline X = aX \Leftrightarrow \overline A A \overline X = \overline a \cdot a X \Leftrightarrow \overline A A \overline X = |a|^{2}X$$

I don't see how this makes $|a|^{2}$ and eigenvalue of $\overline A A$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A \bar x = ax$ then $\bar A x = \bar a\bar x$ and
$$
A\bar A x = \bar a A \bar x = \bar a a x = |a|^2x.
$$

Answer (score 1):

We have $A \overline X = aX$ and $\overline A X = \overline a \overline X$ so
$$
A \overline A X = \vert a \vert^2 X.
$$
To obtain the second equality, we applied
$$
\phi : M \mapsto \overline M
$$
and we used the fact that $\phi(AB)=\phi(A)\phi(B)$, $\phi(\lambda A)=\overline \lambda \phi(A)$ and $\phi^2(A)=A$ for all $A \in \Bbb M_n$ and $\lambda \in \Bbb C$.